# how to upload image when its show 500 error in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

i want upload image but its show below error how to solve this problem, because other format of html working fine ..i want use in angularjs

> 500 (Internal Server Error)

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files)"/>
```

```js
$scope.uploadFile = function(files) {
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append("file", files[0]);
  $http.post(http://www.example.com/id/123, fd, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  }).success(res => {
    var data = res.headers.get('application/json');
    console.log(data);
  }).error(function(err) {
    console.log('sss');
  });
};
```

but when i check use below format its working fine but i want response because i need save into database

```
 <form action="http://www.example.com/id/123" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Upload: <input type="file" name="upload_image"><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
 </form>
```

Comment: That means something is going wrong on your server. It's impossible for us to tell you what the problem is by just looking at your client-side code. Check your servers error logs and report the error.

Comment: i don't have permission i discuess with server manager they send me  form code its working fine...but how to use this code in angularjs

Comment: There's no reason explaining how to work with AngularJS if there's something wrong on the server.

Comment: is my code its correct ?

Comment: but how to html code working fine. .?if there is issue in server side

Comment: If the html works fine, then you aren't accurately recreating said functionality in angular. One obvious difference is the input name.

Comment: it looks like you are missing part of the URL (your "working" example builds `http://www.example.com/id/123`, while your code snippet ***looks like*** it would build `http://www.example.com/123`, depending on what the value of `properties.customerUploadImage_Path` contains);  aside from that, I cringe whenever I see `angular.element(this).scope()` in use, that just **SCREAMS** of confusion about how the framework operates.

Comment: i @edit my post url..if you confuse

Comment: also, don't use `.success` and `.error`, they are deprecated.  use `.then` instead.

Comment: You still haven't shown a [mcve] of the issue.  another example of missing information, where is `this.files` defined?

Comment: no where i define.. ?

Comment: what does that mean?  are you saying that `this.files` doesn't exist?  It is very likely that your server error 500 is happening because you aren't passing a file to the server at all, since your function appears to be expecting an array of files that don't seem to be coming from anywhere.  That *entire* `onchange` handler just looks odd, why are you calling it that way? and why aren't you using `ng-model` with `ng-change` instead?

Comment: if you have example please show me... i need help ..thanks for your cooperation

Comment: files in parameter   $scope.uploadFile = function(files) {

Comment: yes, you are ***accepting*** files as a parameter when you call the function, but you don't appear to be ***passing*** anything valid....   `angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files)` would imply that whatever `this` is, it has a `files` property.  you aren't showing that part of the code here at all.

Comment: but when i $scope.uploadFile = function(files) {
  console.log(files[0]); its show file name

Comment: File {name: "3e.jpg", lastModified: 1481127158636, lastModifiedDate:

Answer (score 0):

its working for me.

```
    <form id="data" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <input type="file" id="file" ng-model="files" name="upload_image">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

 $("form#data").submit(function(){

        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {         
                $scope.showimage= response.image_path; 
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });

        return false;
    });
```